# Как сохранить фрагмент при очистке памяти?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

При открытии новой активности с помощью `startActivityForResult` (из фрагмента, т. к. стоят табы), первая `Activity` уничтожается для очистки памяти (Пробовал на `API 19`, на остальных `Activity` не уничтожается).
Как сохранить фрагмент с данными?

`setRetainInstance(true)`, как я понял, с очисткой памяти не работает. Думал, что поможет метод `onSaveInstanceState`, но только где его применять?

### Создание фрагмента

```
 fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 FragmentHistory fragmentHistory = new FragmentHistory();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragmentHistory);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

### Сохранение данных во фрагменте

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("list", (Serializable) posts);

}
```

### После пересоздания Activity вывожу данные в onCreate фрагмента

```
 if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        posts = new ArrayList<>();
    }else{
        posts = (ArrayList<Posts>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Операционная система имеет право убрать из памяти фрагменты и активити, если не хватает памяти. Не надо их пытаться сохранить, это нормальная ситуация. В большинстве случаев достаточно сохранить состояние, чтобы при повторном создании все могло вернуться "как было", для этого используются `onSaveInstanceState()` и `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Применяются они следующим образом. Однажды наступает момент, после которого сохранение активити с его фрагментами и вьюхами операционная система не гарантирует. Тогда вызывается метод `onSaveInstanceState()`, аргументом которого вам дается объект `Bundle`. Вы в него сохраняете все данные, которе будут необходимы для восстановления. Делаете это так, как будто вы 100% уверены, что активити сейчас выгрузят из памяти.

Если активити не было выгружено, то оно продолжит работу. Если было выгружено, а затем создано заново, то в методы `onCreate()` и `onRestoreInstanceState()` дадут тот же самый `Bundle`, в который вы все сохраняли в `onSaveInstanceState()`. На основе сохраненных вами же данных разместите все нужное в интерфейсе так, чтобы пользователь ничего не заметил.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать MVP библиотеку [Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy). Кроме того, что вы сразу получите правильную архитектуру приложения, библиотека за вас будет заботиться о восстановлении старого состояния при возврате к выгруженной из памяти активити.

Есть иллюстрация работы в докладе одного из создателей, посмотрите вот с этого места: https://youtu.be/KZ0j2K9VAf8?t=4m53s
Если понравится, то возвращайтесь к самому началу, презентация неплохо описывает работу с библиотекой.